# to write a list with nested dictionary to csv file

Tags: json, python-2.7, list, dictionary, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export some API JSON data to a csv. I've tried alot of methods refered here but I'm getting the error.

[My json file is as attached:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVFbY.png)

```
[{u'src': {}, u'product': u'WEB_MPS', u'name': 
u'DOMAIN_MATCH',u'explanation':
    {u'osChanges': [], 
    u'malwareDetected': 
    {u'malware': 
               [{
                        u'md5Sum': u'www.jfaewrwergwea.com', 
                        u'name': u'Raxxxxxe.WCry.InfectionFail'}]
               }}, 

      u'vlan': 0, u'sensorIp': u'10.165.100.31', u'occurred': u'2017-08-24 01:54:54 +0530',
      u'alertUrl':u'', u'applianceId': u'002590879266', u'rootInfection': 7971, u'id': 860438060, 
      u'action': u'notified', u'sensor': u'W-inline', u'dst': {u'mac': u'00:1b:17:00:01:10'}, u'severity': u'MINR'},


{u'src': {}, u'product': u'WEB_MPS', u'name': u'DOMAIN_MATCH', 
u'explanation': {u'osChanges': [], u'malwareDetected': 
{u'malware': [{u'md5Sum': u'www.iuqerea.com', u'name': u'Raxxxxre.WCry.InfectionFail'}]}}, 
u'vlan': 0, u'sensorIp': u'10.165.100.31', u'occurred': u'2017-08-23 19:52:56 +0530', 
u'alertUrl': u'', u'applianceId': u'002590879266', u'rootInfection': 7950, u'id': 860401215, 
u'action': u'notified', u'sensor': u'W0-FW-inline', u'dst': {u'mac': u'00:1b:17:00:01:10'}, u'severity': u'MINR'},
```

How can i get my python code to convert??

Comment: What error are you exactly getting ? what have you tried till now ?

Comment: The presence of single-quotes and the tell-tale `u` indicate your file is not JSON.  It appears to be a string representation of a list of python dictionaries.